# How do I retrieve the url a desktop shortcut is pointing to?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows

I need to retrieve a url from shortcuts on Windows and Linux using python. 
The shortcuts have the same name but different links.

How do I actually retrieve the url from the shortcuts?

Comment: For Windows, see [shell links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/links). Are you okay with depending on PyWin32? If so, it's a relatively simple matter to create an instance of `CLSID_ShellLink` with the [`IPersistFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ipersistfile) interface; load the .lnk file; get the [`IShellLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkw) interface; and finally get the target path.

Comment: For an [Internet shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/internet-shortcuts), we can create an instance of `CLSID_InternetShortcut` with the `IPersistFile` interface; load the .url file; get the [`IUniformResourceLocator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/dd565673(v=vs.85)) interface; and finally get the target URL.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop shortcuts in most desktop environments are just some machine readable files. I guess there is no way around parsing those files and retrieving the information you need that way.

Note: The format of those files might differ substantially from desktop environment to desktop environment.

Comment: The data has to be somewhere?

Comment: Yes, for example on a gnome / kde desktop (linux) its in the file. Try `cd ~/Desktop && cat "name_of_short_cut"`